# Can I create a build a dynamic where clause using the entries from a table

Tags: sql, teradata

I am having a Metadata table as below:

```
RULE_NAME      COL_NAME   COL_VAL
RULE_1     COL_1         ABC
RULE_1     COL_5         XYZ
RULE_2     COL_2         123
RULE_2     COL_3         A2d5
RULE_2     COL_8         X0IL
RULE_3     COL_1         PQR
RULE_3     COL_7         9789
```

I need to generate a WHERE clause using the data from this table. the WHERE clause should be like this:

```
WHERE
(COL_1 = 'ABC' AND COL_5 = 'XYZ') --from Rule 1 records
OR
(COL_2 = '123' AND COL_3 = 'A2D5' AND COL_8 = 'X0IL') --From Rule 2 records
OR
(COL_1 = 'PQR' AND COL_7 = '9789') --from Rule 3 records
```

Is this possible to do with normal SQL (I am on Teradata)? Can someone give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following returns each of the clauses on a separate line:

```
select oreplace(max(case when seqnum = 1 then clause else '' end) ||
                MAX(case when seqnum = 2 then clause else '' end) ||
                MAX(case when seqnum = 3 then clause else '' end)
               ), ')(', ') and (')
from (select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by rule_name order by col_name) as seqnum,
             ('(' || COL_NAME || ' = ' || '''' || col_val || ''')') as clause
      from t
     ) t
group by rule_name
```

Is that close enough?

If you don't have the 'oreplace' function, you can do something like:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then clause else '' end) ||
       MAX(case when seqnum = 2 then clause else '' end) ||
       MAX(case when seqnum = 3 then clause else '' end) || ' 1=1 OR'
from (select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by rule_name order by col_name) as seqnum,
             ('(' || COL_NAME || ' = ' || '''' || col_val || ''') and') as clause
      from t
     ) t
group by rule_name
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Teradata doesn't support oreplace function. I think being on Teradata itself limits the solutions for this.

Comment: thank you. a little tweaking on that should do the job for me..:-)

Comment: @user1987381 . . . This is challenging.  I didn't realize Teradata was so limited in string functionality.  For instance, I thought *all* databases except SQL Server (and Access and Sybase) had functions for string concatenation in aggregation ;).

Comment: There is are freely available UDFs available at http://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/teradata-udfs-for-popular-oracle-functions - This includes the equivalent of `oreplace()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is general Oracle example based on scott.emp table. Covers both EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and REF CURSOR:

```
DECLARE
  v_sql           VARCHAR2(200);
  v_tab_name      VARCHAR2(200):= 'scott.emp';
  v_field_name    VARCHAR2(200):= 'job';
  v_list          VARCHAR2(200):= '''MANAGER'', ''CLERK''';
BEGIN
  v_sql:= 'SELECT * FROM '|| v_tab_name ||' WHERE '||v_field_name ||' IN (:v)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_list;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
END;
/

DECLARE
  emp_cur_rc      SYS_REFCURSOR;
  emp_rec         scott.emp%ROWTYPE;
--
  v_sql           VARCHAR2(200);
  v_tab_name      VARCHAR2(200):= 'scott.emp';
  v_field_name    VARCHAR2(200):= 'job';
  v_list          VARCHAR2(200):= '''MANAGER'', ''CLERK''';
BEGIN
  v_sql:= 'SELECT * FROM '|| v_tab_name ||' WHERE '||v_field_name ||' IN ('||v_list||')';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
  dbms_output.put_line('EXECUTE IMMEDIATE example: '||v_sql||chr(13));
--
  OPEN emp_cur_rc FOR v_sql;
  LOOP
    FETCH emp_cur_rc INTO emp_rec;
    EXIT WHEN emp_cur_rc%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line('REFCURSOR example: '||emp_rec.empno||chr(9)||emp_rec.ename||chr(9)||emp_rec.job);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE emp_cur_rc;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this (untested)?  Perhaps you could supply your desired results.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE 
(
   (COL_Name = 'COL_1' AND COL_Val = 'ABC') 
   OR (COL_Name = 'COL_5' AND COL_Val = 'XYZ')
)
OR 
(
   (COL_Name = 'COL_2' AND COL_Val = '123') 
   OR (COL_Name = 'COL_3' AND COL_Val = 'A2D5') 
   OR (COL_Name = 'COL_8' AND COL_Val = 'X0IL')
) 
OR 
(
   (COL_Name = 'COL_1' AND COL_Val = 'PQR') 
   OR (COL_Name = 'COL_7' AND COL_Val = '9789')
)
```

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear, but, the WHERE clause itself is the result that I need. Basically, I am trying to build a WHERE clause dynamically using the entries from the table.